# create pretty url in yii2 not work

Tags: yii2, pretty-urls

I want use **pretty url** in **yii2**

in web directory **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

In **config/web.php**:

```
'urlManager' => [
     'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
     'baseUrl' => '/',
     'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
     'showScriptName' => false,
     'enableStrictParsing' => true,
     'rules' => [
         '/' => 'view/index',
         'about' => 'view/about',
         'contact' => 'site/contact',
         'login' => 'site/login',
         'logout' => 'site/logout',
         'captcha' => 'site/captcha',
         'signup' => 'site/signup',
     ],
 ],
```

when url is `localhost` page loads  `view/index` like urlmanager
but on `localhost/about` or `localhost/about.php` or any other url to load `view/about`, it loads `view/index` again.

Comment: Do you have two controllers? ViewController with actions for index and about and SiteController with actions contact, login, logout, captcha, signup? The rules will be used only if enablePrettyUrl is set to true - update your post if you have changed this already.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should change from

`enablePrettyUrl=>false`

to

`enablePrettyUrl=>true`

Comment: i change from enablePrettyUrl=>false to enablePrettyUrl=>true but not work

Answer (score 0):

change with

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class'=>'yii\web\UrlManager', 
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        //'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
        //.....
        ],
    ],
```